# Markdown bug: [`foo`](url) produces wrong output in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

```
[`foo`](http://example.com)
```

Should produce: [`foo`](http://example.com).

This works in questions and answers, but inside comments, it produces this instead: [codefoo/code](http://example.com) — test comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479489/can-a-program-output-a-copy-of-itself/1479500#1479500).

[image: bug]

Comment: [`foo`](http://example.com)

Comment: [`foo`](http://example.com) foo? edit: Jinx!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21915/what-markdown-is-available-for-use-within-comments

Comment: the same is true of the italics and bold markdown combined with inline links in comments. [*foo*](http://example.com) and [**foo**](http://example.com) ... if you move the asterisks to outside the link, you get the right effect but the links break... *[foo](http://example.com)* and **[foo](http://example.com)**

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, it isn't generating the `<` and `>` parts of the tags. Just for my own sanity: [`foo`](http://example.com) compared to my comment...? Works!